# How can I import photos into Lightroom from my iPhone without getting the videos?

Tags: lightroom, iphone

I am importing photos from my iPhone 4S into Lightroom 3.4.1. I don't want to import the videos. How do I tell Lightroom not to import video without me having to untick all the individual videos? I couldn't see an option to ignore video.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lightroom does in fact have an option to filter or sort on the media type. In your case, you want to filter out the MOV files from the JPG files. All you have to do is select the **Sort> Media Type** option at the bottom of the import window. This will sort the files by media type, and then give you the option to select a range of photos, and uncheck them all with a single box.

[image]

Comment: I deleted my previous answer, as I was wrong in saying it was not possible before.